# Fourier transform of $g(x - \frac{xy}{f}, y)$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Let $g(x,y)$ have Fourier transform $G(k_x, k_y)$.

I am interested in the Fourier transform of $g(x - \frac{xy}{f}, y)$ for some $f > 0$.

I've gotten part of the way there using the separability and dilation properties of the Fourier transform, but am stuck past a certain point:

\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x - \frac{xy}{f}, y) e^{-i2\pi(xk_x + yk_y)} \mathrm d x \mathrm dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g\left(x(1-\frac{y}{f}), y\right) e^{-i2\pi xk_x} \mathrm dx \right] e^{-i2\pi y k_y} \mathrm dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left| 1 - \frac{y}{f} \right|} G\left(\frac{k_x}{1-\frac{y}{f}}, y\right) e^{-i2\pi y k_y} \mathrm dy
\end{align}

I'm unsure how to proceed from here — I could try integration by substitution with $u = 1 - \frac{y}{f}$, but this gives an integral that I'm unsure how to tackle further:

\begin{align}
& \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{|u|} G\left(\frac{k_x}{u}, f(1-u)\right) e^{-i2\pi f(1-u)k_y} (-f) \mathrm du \\
&= f e^{-i2\pi f} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{|u|} G\left(\frac{k_x}{u}, f(1-u)\right) e^{-i2\pi u (-fk_y)} \mathrm du 
\end{align}

**EDIT:**
It's also interesting to simply consider the Fourier transform of $g(x - \frac{xy}{f}, y)$ at $k_y=0$. Perhaps this integral is easier to solve?

\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left| 1 - \frac{y}{f} \right|} G\left(\frac{k_x}{1-\frac{y}{f}}, y\right) \mathrm dy \\
&= f \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|u|} G\left( \frac{k_x}{u}, f(1-u) \right) \mathrm du
\end{align}

Comment: What compels you to believe that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: I've gotten to this integral by way of trying to generalize the [Fourier slice theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-slice_theorem). In the limit as $f \to \infty$, you get the original Fourier slice theorem, which has a closed-form solution. Beyond this, I don't have any reason to believe closed form exists.

Comment: Also, by following the proof of the Fourier slice theorem, it suffices to just consider the Fourier transform of $g(x-\frac{xy}{f}, y)$ at $k_y=0$. I've updated the original question to include this integral.